# Select element in where clause using join - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a query in which I am getting data using joins on multiple tables. The problem is in join of "vendor_products" table. I want to get data from it using a where clause and i am giving the value of vendor_id from the select element. If I hard code the value the data is coming but if I used the "orders_vendor_id", the query did not worked.

```
Order::select(
        'orders.vendor_id as vendor_id',
        'order_items.product_id as product_id',
        'vendor_products.stock_id as stock_id',
        'vendors.stock as stock',
    )
    ->join('order_items',function($join){
        $join->on('order_items.orders_id', '=','orders.id')
        ->whereNotNull('final_delivery_price');
    })
    ->join('vendor_products',function($join){
        $join->on('vendor_products.product_id', '=','order_items.product_id')
        ->where('vendor_products.vendor_id', 'orders.vendor_id');
    })
    ->join('vendors',function($join){
        $join->on('vendors.id', '=','orders.vendor_id');
    })
    ->where('orders.status', 'delivered')
    ->where('orders.created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
    ->groupBy('orders.vendor_id','order_items.product_id','vendor_products.vendor_stock_id','vendors.vendor_stock')
    ->orderBy('order_items.product_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

'where'   method in query builder take the third argument as value not column (the second argument is '=' by default)
if you want to compare by column value ... use whereColumn instead:

```
 ->join('vendor_products',function($join){
        $join->on('vendor_products.product_id', '=','order_items.product_id')
        ->whereColumn('vendor_products.vendor_id', 'orders.vendor_id');
    })
```

more about whereColumn in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using DB::raw in where clause

```
Order::select(
            'orders.vendor_id as vendor_id',
            'order_items.product_id as product_id',
            'vendor_products.stock_id as stock_id',
            'vendors.stock as stock',
        )
        ->join('order_items',function($join){
            $join->on('order_items.orders_id', '=','orders.id')
            ->whereNotNull('final_delivery_price');
        })
        ->join('vendor_products',function($join){
            $join->on('vendor_products.product_id', '=','order_items.product_id')
            ->where('vendor_products.vendor_id', DB::raw('orders.vendor_id'));
        })
        ->join('vendors',function($join){
            $join->on('vendors.id', '=','orders.vendor_id');
        })
        ->where('orders.status', 'delivered')
        ->where('orders.created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
        ->groupBy('orders.vendor_id','order_items.product_id','vendor_products.vendor_stock_id','vendors.vendor_stock')
        ->orderBy('order_items.product_id');
```